# How does boolean operator work on string in python

Tags: python

```
True and "asdf" or "qwer"
```

result => "asdf"

```
False and "asdf" or "qwer"
```

result => "qwer"

I can't understand how those things work. I thought that boolean operator on string would make type error, but it didn't. Is it something like predefined statement, for instance "a if b else c"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python *and* and *or* operations stop when the answer is determined and return the value of the last object scanned. They do not return *True* or *False*. I love this feature and find myself using it all the time.

Since non-empty strings count as True

```
True and "asdf" or absolutely_anything_here_or_following
```

stops calculating when it hits the *or* because the answer is now determined (one of the *or* values is true), and returns the last thing it checked ("asdf"). No further operands are even inspected.

On the other hand, when

```
False and "asdf" or absolutely_anything_here
```

hits the *or*, it doesn't know the anwser yet so continues to the next operand. As long as absolutely_anything_here is the last operation, the answer is determined and the last thing scanned is returned.

Answer (score 3):

`and` and `or` work just like the familiar boolean operators - they return true if both of their operands are true and false if one of their operands are true, respectively.

They also short circuit, just like `&&` and `||`.

However, in Python, where anything can be interpreted as being `True` or `False` in a boolean context, there is an additional fact - it will return the first operand that evaluated to `True` or evaluated to `False` in a boolean context, when it has enough information to stop evaluation. (This is as opposed to constructing and returning a real boolean `True` or `False`.) This is okay to do because if it is boolean evaluated it will evaluate to the boolean it would have returned if not for this fact.

Thus (note that `""` is evaluated to `False` in a boolean context):

```
>>> "" and "a"
''
>>> "a" and "b"
'b'
>>> "a" and ""
''
>>>


>>> "" or ""
''
>>> "a" or ""
'a'
>>> "" or "a"
'a'
>>> "a" or "b"
'a'

>>> "" or False
False
>>> "" or True
True

>>> False and ""
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Before the Python conditional operator:

```
>>> age=20
>>> 'legal' if age>=21 else 'not legal'
'not legal'
```

There used to be 'cargo code' as a work around based on indexing tuples:

```
>>> ('not legal','legal')[age>=21]
'not legal'
>>> age=22
>>> ('not legal','legal')[age>=21]
'legal'
```

You can disassemble the two alternatives that you posted to see what is happening under the hood:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f():
...    x=True and "asdf" or "qwer"
...    y=False and "asdf" or "qwer"
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (True)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       12
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('asdf')
              9 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     15
        >>   12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('qwer')
        >>   15 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          18 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (False)
             21 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       30
             24 LOAD_CONST               1 ('asdf')
             27 JUMP_IF_TRUE_OR_POP     33
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               2 ('qwer')
        >>   33 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             39 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see the values you see pop'ing up to the value you are seeing. You can also look at the short circuiting behavior of [boolean operators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=short%20circuit#boolean-operations-and-or-not) and see this is documented behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Object in python considered True of False(like, '', None)

The result of the boolean result rely on the last value that could determine the result.

> print 'aa' and True

True

'aa' is True, but it can't determine the result, so the result turn to True

while

```
print True and 'aa'
```

'aa'

But operator or is different from operator and, see

```
print None and True
```

None

The first None is considered False, and it could determine the last result,
so it print 'None'

while

```
print False or 'bb'
```

'bb'

because the first False cant determine the final result!

Answer (score 0):

**First Example**
Python scans and evaluates from left to right.

In your first example

`True and "asdf" or "qwer"`

evaluates to

`"asdf" or "qwer"`

Because a non-empty string is True, Python short circuits (ignores the second operand) and returns the first operand `"asdf"`. Remember `True or x` will return `True` regardless of the value of `x`.

**Second example**

`False and "asdf" or "qwer"`

this evaluates to

`False or "qwer"`

This time we don't short circuit on the first operand (we don't have enough information yet), and Python needs to check the second operand `qwer`, which evaluates to `True` in a boolean context (remember it's not empty), and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations for operators:
--not is evaluated first;
--and is evaluated next;
--or is evaluated last. 
as per your question first "and" operator is evaluated since Since non-empty strings count as True. hence True and "asdf" becomes True than True or "qwer" also becomes true. SO result becomes "asdf"
In second False and "asdf" becomes false and false and "qwer"  becomes false. hence it is false so it return last thing it has checked "qwer".

Comment: This question has good quality answers including the accepted one. If you want to answer such an old question you should try to contribute additional information or quality