# Control flow in python with strings

Tags: python, control-flow

I have a very basic snippet of code.

```
print("a" or "b")
>> a
```

I'm not entirely sure what I expected to happen.
Why does this print "a", and in general how are strings handled with python control flow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do boolean operators work on strings in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889732/how-does-boolean-operator-work-on-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

In python, empty strings evaluate to `False` in a boolean context, while non-empty strings are `True`.